# Creating a responsive wordpress contact page like this picture:

Tags: wordpress, html, responsive-design, center

I'm trying to reproduce this page on my wordpress website.(http://lilyvalley.co/previews/)
The page should be responsive.

I don't know if my approach is wrong, but what I tried are the following:
- To have this centered effect, I tried to use the image as a background and put the text and the form over it. the result: everything is off position when I resize the window.
- I tried to create a table where each row and columns contains something( image,text,form)
  also with no good results.

I need help to determine what approach to take in this case to have all the element in their place and when I resize the window, they are resized accordingly. 
The gold bar that you see is also part of that page.( the picture says it all).

Appreciate the help here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout [learnlayout.com](http://learnlayout.com) to learn the basics of div based markup

**Learn the Basics, Terminology, and Responsive Design Too:**

- [CSS Glossary](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/29/useful-glossaries-for-web-designers-and-developers/)
- [CSS Basics](http://www.cssbasics.com/)
- [CSS Beginner](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/)
- [Guide to Responsive Design for Beginners](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design)
- [10 Basic Responsive Design Tips](http://www.splio.com/responsive/)
- [Creating a Mobile First Responsive Design](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/)

Comment: This is of a great help. Thank you so much for sharing this with me.